# VB.Net how does one call a function name retrieved from a table?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

In VB.Net how does one call a Parameterised function name retrieved from a table?

My Parameterised Function Name is below

procTextToDBTemp(Application.StartupPath & "\" & strFileName)

from above function i Stored procTextToDBTemp into the SQL Table

How can call that function in the Vb.net

How can i do that

Please help me

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into reflection, which allows you to evaluate a string as if it was a line of code. I've not done it in  VB so can't give you specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your Support

I got the answer of my Question,i want to share the answer with all of you...

```
lDataTable = objCon.ReturnDataTable("select codeNo,FunctionName from Format_Master  where codeNo='" & Mid(LTrim(gstrpdffilename), 1, 5) & "'")

If Not lDataTable Is Nothing Then
    If lDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        CallByName(Me, lDataTable.Rows(0).Item(1), CallType.Method, "('" & Application.StartupPath & "\" & strFileName & "')", lDataTable.Rows(0).Item(0))

    End If
End If
```